# Angular router intercepts link to RSS feed and shows index.html instead

Tags: angularjs

```
<a href="/feed">RSS</a>
```

How do I get angular ng-router to ignore the handling of this link?

Comment: I doubt Angular is doing anything here. My guess is that you have a server-side URL rewriter (as you would to run Angular in HTML5 mode) that is intercepting this URL

Comment: I don't think that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add

```
target="_self"
```

to the anchor tag.  Any anchor that contains a target is ignored by ng-route.

Comment: Thanks. I figured out `_blank` worked -- but `_self` is good too.

Comment: Glad it is working for you!  As an additional note, any of the target attributes should work.  It would just depend on where you wanted the linked document to open.